# WCF Services (with RIA)

Tags: wcf, wcf-ria-services

I am new to WCF and WCF derived services.

I am using VS 2010, silverlight 4, ria services 4.

Recently I created plain WCF REST services (no RIA, no SOAP) with my endpoint (using wsHttpBinging):

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="wsBehavior" binding="wsHttpBinding"             bindingConfiguration="wsbinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"/>

<behaviors>
 <endpointBehaviors>
 <behavior name="wsBehavior">
  <webHttp/>
 </behavior>.........
```

I use this service from silverlight 4 client and everything works fine.

THEN, i created new project using "silverlight Business application" template which used RIA service. Now the web.config uses DomainServices and when i add wsHttpBind endpoint I doesnot work. I know i am not doing this correctly and i cant find any help online so far.

What I am trying to do is creat a RESTful WCF application with RIA (no SOAP) and that i can use from silverlight 4 client. For some reason i cannot get the service working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think silverlight supports wsHttpBinding.

Comment: Thats what I had read but it does work in WCf/.net 4/ Now i am trying to get the right web.config to work with RIA

Comment: First of All this should be Comment.And BTW wsHttpBinding used to Create Json Response and create EndPoint Also!!!!